# Using cin.getline with string declared

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
string line,line2;
char dude[20];
cin.getline(dude,20);
fstream myfile ("example.txt",ios::in);

if(!myfile)
{
    cout<<"Not Found! ";
    system("pause");
}  
while (!myfile.eof())
{

    getline(myfile,line);
    cout<<line;

}
myfile.close();
exit(0);
  }
```

This works but if i do this:

```
int main () {
string line,line2,dude;
```

It gives me an error.
[Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_istream::getline(std::string&, int)'
WHY?

Comment: *"WHY?"* Well, because there is no overload of `getline()` that takes a `string` and an `int`. Which part of the error message do you find unclear?

Comment: There are more flaws in your code, like: `while (!myfile.eof())`.

Answer (score 2):

- `std::cin.getline()` expects a `char*` buffer ([docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline))
- `std::getline()` expects a `std::string` buffer ([docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline))

When you change the type, you have to change which function you call, too.

Answer (score 1):

`char buf[20]` is not a string, it is a character array. If you terminate the array with a '\0' byte, then it can be said to be a c-string. Still not a `std::string`, though.

The function `cin.getline()` expects two parameters: a pointer to an array of characters and a count of how many characters the buffer supports - it then populates it with a c-string from cin.

There is no variant of `cin.getline()` which supports a std::string. For that, you need to use `std::getline(iostream, string)`, e.g.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```